# memory leak in std::vector representing 2D data

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have written a simple templated Matrix class to use with my main application which is manipulating data matricies.  The truncated Matrix code is:

```
template <typename T> 
class Matrix{
   private:
      std::vector<T> matrixRepresentation;
      bool transposed;
  public: 
  Matrix(int r, int c);
  int maxRows;
  int maxCols;
  void setMatrixValue(int row, int col, T val);
  T getMatrixValue(int row, int col);
};

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int r, int c){
   maxRows = r;
   maxCols = c;
   matrixRepresentation.resize((r+1)*(c+1));
}   

template <typename T>
void Matrix<T>::setMatrixValue(int row, int col, T val){
   matrixRepresentation[row + col*maxCols] = val;
}

template <typename T>
T Matrix<T>::getMatrixValue(int row, int col){
   return matrixRepresentation[row + col*maxCols];
}
```

As you can see I am just representing a 2D matrix as a vector and giving wrapper methods to hide that fact.  Even though I resize the stack variable matrixRepresentation to

```
(r+1)(c+1)
```

I end up with memory corruption problems later in the code and valgrind tells me the following:

```
==3753==    at 0x8049777: Matrix<int>::setMatrixValue(int, int, int) (in a.out)
==3753==    by 0x8049346: DataFile::readAllData() (ina.out)
==3753==    by 0x8049054: DataFile::DataFile(char const*) (in a.out)
==3753==    by 0x804C386: main (in a.out)
==3753==  Address 0x42cc970 is 0 bytes after a block of size 5,600 alloc'd
==3753==    at 0x4026351: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
==3753==    by 0x804A603: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned int, 
            void   const*) (in /a.out)
==3753==    by 0x8049F0D: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> 
            >::_M_allocate(unsigned int) (in a.out)
==3753==    by 0x804A181: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> 
            >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, 
            std::allocator<int> > >, unsigned int, int const&) (in a.out)
==3753==    by 0x8049AEF: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> 
            >::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, 
            std::allocator<int> > >, unsigned int, int const&) (in a.out)
==3753==    by 0x80499AB: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::resize(unsigned int,
            int) (in a.out)
==3753==    by 0x8049709: Matrix<int>::Matrix(int, int) (in a.out)
==3753==    by 0x80492AD: DataFile::readAllData() (in a.out)
==3753==    by 0x8049054: DataFile::DataFile(char const*) (in a.out)
==3753==    by 0x804C386: main (in a.out)
```

The readAllData() method (the user of this matrix class) is simply reading from a text file and trying to populate the matrix

```
void DataFile::readAllData(){
   int currentValue;
   featureMatrix = new Matrix<int>((theHeader.totalNumSamples),
   (theHeader.numFeatures));

    if (infile.is_open()){
       if (!infile.eof()){
          for (int row=0; row < theHeader.totalNumSamples; row++){
            for (int col=0; col < theHeader.numFeatures; col++){
               infile >> currentValue;
               featureMatrix->setMatrixValue(row, col, currentValue);
             }
          }
       }
       else{
          cout << "EOF reached before we should have been done!  Closing file";
          infile.close();
       }
   }
   else cout << "File not open when attempting to read data";

   infile.close();
}
```

The header values are valid (e. g. theHeader.totalNumSamples = 15, theHeader.numFeatures = 100).

Please let me know if I can provide any more information, I could really use some help with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This snippet (which appears twice in your code):

```
 [row + col*maxCols]
```

Isn't correct.  It should be `[row * maxCols + col]` or `[col*maxRows + row]`

And for that matter you don't need to allocate `matrixRepresentation.resize((r+1)*(c+1));`  you can allocate instead `matrixRepresentation.resize(r*c);`

You should do the math on the extreme cases (like access to element `(maxRows-1,maxCols-1)` to check this yourself for understanding purposes).

Comment: Oh man, thanks so much.  I would have continued looking past that for many hours.

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```
template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const int r, const int c) :
   maxRows(r),
   maxCols(c),
   matrixRepresentation((r+1)*(c+1))
{}
```

It might or might not solve it, but it is very much worth a try, if only to rule out trouble in the initialization of the `Matrix`.

Update:  @ChrisA.'s answer is better.  Try that first.

Comment: Besides being better code, the behavior should be equivalent.

Comment: @pmr is right:  it should be equivalent.  The (maybe unnecessary) test is only to prove that it is indeed equivalent in the OP's case.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what Valgrind's specific issue is, but I found this:

```
maxRows = r;
maxCols = c;
matrixRepresentation.resize((r+1)*(c+1));
```

In your constructor then you are creating, say, a 3x3 matrix but are allocating 16 places, not 9. While this shouldn't be a problem necessarily, you're likely hiding other bugs by having this padding in place. My take would be to only allocate the space you need, and if you find yourself crashing or otherwise behaving badly, fix the issues therein instead of compensating for them in your Matrix implementation.

Comment: Yeah you caught me that was exactly it.  I was having off-by-one issues and threw that in there as a 'quick fix' even though it was just hiding the problem.  I don't know how many times I have to do that to learn that it's better to take the time up front and find the real problem.